# Converting a list of hh:mm:ss measures in seconds in python

Tags: python, time

I have a list containing a series of time measures in `hh:mm:ss` format. 
I've managed to convert single elements of the list in seconds using:

```
sum(int(x) * 60 ** i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(saved_column.split(":")))))
```

But when I try to use it on the whole list it returns:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

How can I do it?

Comment: what's `Series` object? Are you using a 3rd party like  _pandas_ etc?

Comment: I'm using Jupyter from Anaconda, is that what you mean? And yes i'm using Pandas,

Answer (score 0):

The code `enumerate(reversed(saved_column.split(":")))))` is operating on a list, in this case 3 items long. Presumably you try to replace `saved_column` with the entire list of values, which gives you the error?

The problem with that approach is that you're then trying to use `enumerate(reversed(saved_column.split(":")))))` over a *Series* of lists.

As such, an easy fix would be to iterate over each item in your Series, which would give you the result for each time measure in your list.

Comment: Thanks, how can iiterate it?

Comment: Search for "pandas iterate over series". Should give you some pointers

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
saved_column = ['11:23:44','10:22:44']
seconds = []
for i in range(len(saved_column)):
  time = saved_column[i].split(":")
  time = list(map(int, time))
  seconds.append(time[0]*3600 + time[1]*60 + time[2])

print (seconds)
```

Comment: I've tried and it returns: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hh'

Comment: you have 'hh' in your list.
I assumed that your list is something like `saved_column = ['11:23:44','10:22:44']` apply the for loop as coded and you will end up with a list seconds which is the list you want

Comment: I have the list like this `['00:09:40',
 '00:09:50',
 '00:10:00',
 '00:10:10',
 '00:10:20']`   I apply your code but still get the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: hh''`

Comment: seems fine to me check it out https://repl.it/HtBX/0 .
Can you write a larger part of code to understand better the result

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the variable which has the whole list to a list in the following way and then run the code again.

```
my_set = set([1,2,3,4])
my_list = list(my_set)
print my_list
```